# Updating text object in Blender 2.81 using python

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I'm trying to update multiple text objects by testing it with changing the current frame (*Please note this will be replaced with different field variables with decimal values in it*) but instead of replacing the number it writes over it and creates several font objects.

How can I fix this so it replaces the previous value and doesn't create all those font objects?

[image: text]

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

def recalculate_text(self):
    font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
    font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current) 
    font_obj = bpy.data.objects.update("Font Object", font_curve)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)

    font_curve2 = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
    font_curve2.body = '2nd Field value: ' + str(scene.frame_current)
    font_obj2 = bpy.data.objects.update("Font Object", font_curve2)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj2)


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_text)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_text)

register()
```

PS: I know I could do this with Animation nodes but I'm trying to get better at scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function recalculate_text which you're having run every frame, is also setup to create a new object every time. Pull the object creation out of the def function. Check this out.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current) 

font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Font Object", font_curve)

scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)

def recalculate_text(scene):
    font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current) 

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_text)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_text)

register()
```

Comment: @.....................Thanks!