# If a specific text object doesn't exist create it, if it does exist just update it. Using python in Blender 2.81

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

Trying to create and check if text objects exist.

My logic is if a specific text object doesn't exist create it, if it does exist update the value using python in Blender 2.81.  At the moment nothing gets created.  The error is:

> > **Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "/Text", line 21, in 
> >     TypeError: CollectionObjects.link(): error with argument 1, "object" -  Function.object expected a Object type, not list
> >     Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console**
> >
> > Which is: this line **scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)**

This code will be placed in another loop hence I'm using an if / else statement to prevent the text objects from being created multiple times.
Trying to alter the working answer code from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165454/updating-text-object-in-blender-2-81-using-python)

What I have:

```
import bpy
w1=[]
font_obj=[]

if font_obj is None: 
    scene = bpy.context.scene

    font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
    font_curve.body = 'Test Variable: ' + str(w1) 
    font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Font Object w1 var", font_curve)
    font_obj.location = (0, 1, 0)

    font_curve2 = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve2")
    font_curve2.body = 'Current Frame plus: ' + str(scene.frame_current) 
    font_obj2 = bpy.data.objects.new("Font Object w2 var", font_curve2)
    font_obj2.location = (0, -1, 0)
    font_obj2.scale = (.5, .5, .5)

else:
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)
    scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj2)

    def recalculate_text(scene):
        font_curve.body = 'Variable1 : ' + str(w1) 
        font_curve2.body = 'Variable2 : ' + str(scene.frame_current+3) 

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_text)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_text)

register()
```

Comment: Does your code not work? Are you getting errors? Please describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot I updated the question to include the link to the working code along with the error code.

Comment: Change `font_obj = []` Setting  to a list, and then check if  `None` will never be True.  instead change to  `font_obj = scene.objects.get("Font Object w1 var")` (and defining scene prior)    This is your error in trying to link an empty list (which isn't same as `None`  However they are Both boolean False) to a collection.  Might find this of interest https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161103/handler-script-updates-in-viewport-but-not-in-render

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks! I made those changes it creates the object but I get an error `line 29, in recalculate_text
NameError: name 'font_curve' is not defined`  but it's already defined when the object is created?   Also line 29 is a blank line.

Comment: Since you have the object `font_curve = font_obj.data`  Your logic is totally snarfed here.  A lot of the code above IMO should be in the handler code not outside.  This will make `font_curve` local to the handler method.  Unless (for example) `font_curve` is defined as a `global` (which you really don't want to do) the handler doesn't know who the outsider is.  Check out the link posted, especially how `text` is passed to one function to return a handler method with that `text` as a local.  If you are new to python recommend searching on "python NameError" or similar at stackoverflow

Comment: @batFINGER  Thanks I did find some good info about handlers https://youtu.be/qHLHcFwXH8o?t=506  still not sure how to get rid of the error yet still looking at work arounds using python