# python code to change a text during the timeline

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on, keyframes, timeline

I'm a physicist teacher and I'm trying to create a code that modifies a text during the timeline evolution. The idea is make a display that show some information such the position of an object while it is moving. For this, I was thinking in make a code that

1. get the information about an object (its position, angle between its edges, this things)
2. create a text showing this information
3. create a key frame to 'save' the information
   and them a loop for repeat this process along the movement of the object.

If someone can help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello ! AFAIK it's unfortunately not possible to keyframe the body of a text. There are alternatives though, you'll have to use custom callbacks or dynamically hide / show different text objects at runtime

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/how-can-i-make-dynamic-text-in-an-animation or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231698/change-text-based-on-frame and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165454/updating-text-object-in-blender-2-81-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are fine with using animation nodes (https://animation-nodes.com/#download) which is an amazing add-on, you can use this node setup:

[image]

animate your objects position...

and you will get:

[image]

---

Here a solution with GN:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Man, I do not have words to express what I'm felling. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: this is amazing lol

Comment: in the meantime you can do this also with geometry nodes ;)